# System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: RECORD_IN_USE_BY_WORKFLOW

Tags: apex, unit-test, leads, failing-tests, lead-conversion

I am trying to convert a `Lead` in a Test Class but i'm facing the exception above.
I searched about this error but it's didn't helpfull. I try to follow these steps to search for a solution: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385353&type=1

But i don't have any active workflow rules, time-based workflows, paused flow interview or approval proccess. And to test the last item, i try to inactivate all `Account`, `Opportunity` and `Leads`, validation rules from my org to verify if could be one of them

There is the part of my code that should convert the Lead

```
Test.startTest();

LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = true LIMIT 1];
Database.LeadConvert leadToConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();

leadToConvert.setLeadId(leadToInsert.Id);
leadToConvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
leadToConvert.setConvertedStatus(ConvertStatus.MasterLabel);

Database.LeadConvertResult leadAlreadyConverted = Database.convertLead(leadToConvert);
System.assert(leadAlreadyConverted.isSuccess());
if(leadAlreadyConverted.isSuccess()){
    leadToConvert.setOpportunityId(opportunityToInsert.Id);
}

Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: Can you check if any trigger handler is calling a flow interview and scheduling an action in future for the lead? Also, please check if there is any active approval process as it is mentioned in the article.

Comment: I searched in my VS Code and don't have any call to a flow interview or scheduling an action. Also i already searched for approval process and i don't find anything

Comment: Can you check the log generated by this test method? It will surely highlight any workflow in action.

Comment: We resolved the problem, i'll update the question with the solution. Thanks for your help, Manuj!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** While we are searching for a solution, we resolve to inactivate each Flow from `Lead`, `Opportunity` and `Account` org. We found a flow that was executed on Create event, and this flow has an assync path, and that was causing the exception. To solve this problem we used a workaround, we create a Boolean field in `Lead` to be used as a entry condition in flow only if this field is `false` and set him as `true` in the test class.